# NSGL: Failed to create OpenGL pixel format

Tags: opengl

My code is here, this returns an error: NSGL: Failed to create OpenGL pixel format

the error callback is the standard callback from glfw.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

if (!glfwInit ()) {
    fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
    return 1;
}
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Hello Triangle", NULL, NULL);

glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

if (!window) {
    fprintf (stderr, "\nERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
    return -1;
}

// start GLEW extension handler
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit ();

// get version info
const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string
printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

// tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

/* OTHER STUFF GOES HERE NEXT */

// close GL context and any other GLFW resources
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

does someone know what the problem is?

Comment: This issue is quite old, but still: Have you found any solution? I`m having it right now.

Comment: still no solution :( sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my OSX Machine, that issue arised due to the stencil buffer depth setting, which was 16 bit. OSX appearently (or the built in graphics cards) can only handle 8 bit. Since I´m not into OpenGL at all, I cannot reason this yet, but I will update the answer as soon as I have a deeper understanding.

The code responsible for setting the buffer depth is the following (corrected version):

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_STENCIL_BITS, 8);
```

which is executed before creating the window with `glfwCreateWindow(...)`

Hope this helps :)